# Async task progress dialog take long time for simple task in android

Tags: android, android-asynctask, progressdialog

This async task when i call , it  take long time , but task is very short , when i directly put code it work ok , but when i use async task it take time , i already find solution from this site ,
[Progress dialog async task taking longer time than expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28124150/progress-dialog-async-task-taking-longer-time-than-expected)
but it not work properly,

```
public class Towing_TaskCollectAmountCash extends AsyncTask<Double,Void,Void>{

private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
Activity activity;


public Towing_TaskCollectAmountCash(Activity activity,Double collectedAmount) {
    this.activity = activity;
    this.collectedAmount=collectedAmount;
    progressDialog=new ProgressDialog(activity);
}

//progress Dialog Showing
@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    progressDialog.setTitle("Please Wait...");
    progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
    progressDialog.setIndeterminate ( true ) ;
    progressDialog.show();
}
@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Double... amount){
     referenceOfDriverWallets=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Wallet").child("Drivers").child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid());
     referenceOfDriverWallets.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener({
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot){
          if(dataSnapshot.child("TotalRideCollection").exists()){
              totalRideCollection= Double.valueOf(dataSnapshot.child("TotalRideCollection").getValue().toString());
            }
        }

         @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        }
});}

//Progress Dialog dismiss
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
    progressDialog.dismiss();
}

}
```

this is main MainActivity calling code

```
Towing_TaskCollectAmountCash obj=new 
Towing_TaskCollectAmountCash(CollectPayment.this,collectedAmount);
obj.execute();
```

Please help me , Thanks in advance

Comment: You dotted out the important part...

Comment: @TheWanderer i update the code , Know please check ..

Comment: There is no need to pack this inside a `AsyncTask`. The Firebase code is already asynchronous. Data will be presented in `onDataChange()`.

Comment: @Barns then how can i show progress dialog ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

Create a class instance for the `ProgressDialog`

```
private ProgressDialog progressDialog = null;
```

Now just a simple method for the `Firebase` call:

```
private Void getData(){
    if(progressDialog == null){
        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
        progressDialog.setTitle("Please Wait...");
        progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
        progressDialog.setIndeterminate ( true ) ;
    }
    progressDialog.show();

     referenceOfDriverWallets=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Wallet").child("Drivers").child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid());
     referenceOfDriverWallets.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener({
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot){
          if(dataSnapshot.child("TotalRideCollection").exists()){
              totalRideCollection= Double.valueOf(dataSnapshot.child("TotalRideCollection").getValue().toString());

              progressDialog.dismiss();
            }
        }

         @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            progressDialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
}
```

If you are calling this from inside an `Activity` the context could be:

`YourActivity.this`

You don't seem to use the `collectedAmount` parameter.

---

**NOTE:**

I have not check the code for querying Firebase. I will just assume it has worked is expected.

Comment: Thank you so much , now it work more better then before , :)